# If a vector space is infinite dimensional then prove that dual space is also infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Consider this question: Let we have a vector space which is infinite dimensional then show that it's dual space is also infinite dimensional.

I have been reading notes on Manifolds from class notes of senior and this was left to do itself.

I have done a course on Linear algebra 2 years ago and followed Hoffman, Kunze but I can't recall now what result I should use and I looked back at it but not sure what result to use. So, can you please give some hints?

Comment: Define a basis of the dual space in terms of a basis of the space, then show you've bijected from one basis to the other.

Comment: A basis of $V$ can be used to construct a set of linearly independent functionals, with cardinality the cardinality of the basis. Thus if $V$ is infinite dimensional, one can find infinitely many independent functionals in $V^*$.